# couchdb replicate one direction doesnt work continuously

Tags: couchdb, replication

i would like to replicate all design docs and some docs that contain field clientId from orginal (A) to replication (B).

i have tried 2 ways but bothe have the same problem:

it updates my design docs continuously but not the normal docs with clientId. they only replicate one time on creation of replication.

**1. try**

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
            -X POST http://admin:*******@mycare.owitec.lan:5984/_replicator \
            -d '{
                "continuous" : true,
                "create_target" : true,
                "source" : {
                                               "url": "http://mycare.owitec.lan:5984/mycare_10001",
                                               "headers": {
                                                 "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46QXNkZmdoKjU9"
                                               }
                                             },
                "target" : {
                                               "url": "http://mycare.owitec.lan:5984/mycare_rep_10001",
                                               "headers": {
                                                 "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46QXNkZmdoKjU9"
                                               }
                                             },
                "filter": "article/clientDataRep"
            }'

    function(doc, req) {
    var v = doc._id.substr(0, 6);
  
    if (v === '_desig' || v === '10001:') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**2. try**

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        -X POST http://admin:********@mycare.owitec.lan:5984/_replicator \
        -d '{
            "continuous" : true,
            "create_target" : true,
            "source" : {
                                           "url": "http://mycare.owitec.lan:5984/mycare_10001",
                                           "headers": {
                                             "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46QXNkZmdoKjU9"
                                           }
                                         },
            "target" : {
                                           "url": "http://mycare.owitec.lan:5984/mycare2_rep_10001",
                                           "headers": {
                                             "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46QXNkZmdoKjU9"
                                           }
                                         },
            "selector": { "clientId": {"$exists": false} }
        }'
```

i also checked both dbs for conflicts and there are none in both. what am i doing wrong? in other dbs where i have both-way-replication (from/to) i have no problems!

Answer (score 1):

it was the validate_doc_update function of a design document that checked 2 things:

if it is a update then you have to be the author or have a certain rule

according to doc.type object was only allowed certain fields and i had old data that didnt conform

the replication was always running i just didnt notice (think about) that the validate_doc_update was filtering it